# Nokia 2330c how to get log file

Tags: java-me, lwuit, logcat, nokia

I'm trying to create simple app  and one of my phones for testing is Nokia 2330c. My question is - is there any way to get connected to this particular model(preferably using cable), get inside and read the log file (similar to android logcat)? And does this model support any GUI like LWUIT or Polsih?

Thanks 
Regs
Me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LWUIT, you will find the Log class to help you to get log info from your code. There is not any program similar to Logcat, sorry.

[Log LWUIT](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cehdfgff.html)

Comment: Thanks Jmunoz, but to see the log file I have to be able to debug on device or to "get inside the phone" and fetch the log file.... That's why I'm looking for any way to connect to the phone. 
Using PC Suite I can only see files that I'm allowed (by nokia) to see. But is there a way to get deeper into the system..?

Comment: You device model is too old...I've only have seen this info about this issue http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/asha/java/start/On-Device_Debugging/